# Jenkins pipeline dockerFingerprintFrom example

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some troubles about `dockerFingerprintFrom` on jenkins pipeline.

The code is as follows:

```
node {
  stage("First stage") {
    dockerFingerprintFrom([dockerfile: "."])
  }
}
```

It does not work.
I don't even know if this correct.
I would like ask if anyone has a practical example to show me ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you specifying in dockerfile? (FROM)